# Apache Airflow - Spark Submit Failing -When running with master 'yarn-client' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, spark-submit

I am new to Spark and Airflow and trying to create a DAG which runs spark submit jobs in pyspark.

In my Ubuntu system I have a user created named 'hadoopusr' through which I manually run my spark submits. All the environment variables are setup in `/.bashrc` under this user.

When I am running the spark-submit manually from the terminal the job is running successfully.

I created a sample DAG file which looks like this:

```py
"""
Apache Airflow DAG Script: Ingestion MVP basic version
"""
#imports
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import sys
#Paths
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/usr/local/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7'
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'bin'))
#Parameters
filename="CDC_DAY1"
file_extension="csv"
batch_id="20191203"
## Define the DAG object
default_args = {
    'owner': 'hadoopusr',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 12, 3),
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}
dag = DAG('MVP_BASIC_2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))
#List of tasks
LandingToRaw = BashOperator(
    task_id='Landing_to_Raw',
    bash_command="spark-submit --master yarn-client /home/soham/Documents/mvp_landing_raw_1.py "+filename+" "+file_extension+" "+batch_id,
    dag=dag,
    run_as_user='hadoopusr')

RawToStaging = BashOperator(
    task_id='Raw_to_Staging',
    bash_command="spark-submit --master yarn-client /home/soham/Documents/mvp_raw_staging_1.py "+filename+" "+file_extension+" "+batch_id+" FULL emp_id",
    dag=dag,
    run_as_user='hadoopusr')

#Dependencies
LandingToRaw >> RawToStaging
```

When I am testing the first task of the DAG using the following command under the same user (hadoopusr) it is throwing an exception like:

```
Running command: spark-submit --master yarn-client /home/soham/Documents/mvp_landing_raw_1.py CDC_DAY1 csv 20191203
[2019-12-04 19:27:52,527] {bash_operator.py:124} INFO - Output:
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,937] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: When running with master 'yarn-client' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,938] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,938] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:290)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,938] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:251)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,938] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:120)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,939] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,939] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,939] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,939] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,940] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,940] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,973] {bash_operator.py:132} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,987] {taskinstance.py:1058} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 136, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2019-12-04 19:27:54,990] {taskinstance.py:1081} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 688, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1020, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 136, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

Am I going wrong some where in configuration or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying run spark in yarn-client mode, for that you need YARN to be configured,
if you are using YARN, you need to set YARN_CONF_DIR to path of yarn configuration,
also you can use spark`s local master mode just run --master local[num_of_threads/*].

Comment: I changed the spark submit to run in --master local[*] mode. The job is starting now. But inside the spark job I am running few hdfs commands. Now in local mode I am getting error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs': 'hdfs'. I didnt get this error in yarn mode.

Comment: what hdfs command you are trying to run? do you use os.system("hdfs dfs -command") ? you`ll need provide some of your code of what you trying to do and the error.

Comment: This got solved. I am using subprocess module. I had to add the HDFS path. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using Airflow to submit a Spark job.
I realized that the problem was because of `EnvironmentFile` variable which is present in the `airflow-webserver.service` file.

For me this got resolved after I copied all the variables like `HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, YARN_HOME, SPARK_HOME, etc`  that I have on `~/.bashrc` to `<EnvironmentFile>` path ,in my case the path was `/etc/sysconfig/airflow` (this is default value, you can check here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/master/scripts/systemd/airflow-webserver.service ). Same variable is also present in the `airflow-scheduler.service`. After copying to `etc/sysconfig/airflow`, I restarted both `airflow-webserver` & `airflow-scheduler` services. Spark job executed successfully from Airflow.

Example: If you have line `export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop` on the bashrc file, you need to keep only `HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop` on the EnvironmentFile (without the export)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when trying to run spark submit via Airflow SparkSubmitOperator. In SparkSubmitOperator, there is an option to send the env_vars and I sent the HADOOP_CONF_DIR, YARN_CONF_DIR as parameters to that env_vars and it fixed the issue. This is the sample view of how my DAG looks like:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["cde", "spark"],
) as dag:
    config = {
        "java_class": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkTC",
        "conf": {"spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion":"false"},
        "verbose": True,
        "application":"/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.7.7.1.7.0-551.jar",
        "env_vars": {"HADOOP_CONF_DIR":"/etc/hadoop", "YARN_CONF_DIR":"/etc/hadoop"},
    }
    submit_job = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id="submit_job",
        **config
    )
```